# JPA/Hibernate map null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We're working with a really old database where dates are stored as numeric values in the database as `YYYYMMDD`, for example, for today (July 16th 2014) it would be stored as `20140716`.

We're currently solving this by implementing our own `AttributeConverter<Date, Long>` which converts `Date` objects to `Long` and vice versa.

However, there's also a constraint on the database that does not allow `NULL` values in the column. The column itself is optional, but if the date is not existing, the date should be persisted as zero (`0`) in stead of `NULL`.

So, what we did in our `AttributeConverter` is the following:

```
@Override
public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(Date input) {
    Long out = 0L;
    if (input != null) {
        Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(input);
        out += (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000);
        out += (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 100;
        out += cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    return out;
}
```

But while debugging we noticed that our converter is not executed when the date is `null`, so it's never converted to zero.

Is there a way we can still force Hibernate (4.3.5.Final) to use our converter, even if the value is `null`?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: Not sure if this is related, I cannot open this link from work: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8697

Comment: That indeed describes our problem and applies to Hibernate 4.3.0.Beta5. The issue itself is unresolved though and no workaround is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have identified, it seems to be a BUG reported [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8697).

The typical workaround (that works perfectly in JPA<2.1) is to map that column to a simple (i.e without `AttributeConverter)` `Long` field/property and to hide it (make it private) and expose another field of type `Date` that converts it.

Comment: We ended up using this approach indeed. Too bad we can't use the converter though.

Comment: This bug has been fixed and will be in the next release. The 5.0.0.Beta1 release is on the maven central if you are willing to use beta releases.