# JPA 2.1 Type Converter doesn't get executed on NULL values

Tags: entitymanager, jpa-2.1, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm testing the new JPA 2.1 Type Converters. I want to avoid NULL String values to be stored in a legacy database as they are not allowed. So I defined the following converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)  
public class CString implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {  

    @Override  
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String str) {  
        if( str == null || str.length() == 0 ) {  
            return " ";
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String str) {
        if( str == null || str.length() == 0 || str.equals(" ") ) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }

}
```

String properties should be converted to a space character if they are NULL, but the converter method's are not executed when the properties are NULL.
I'm trying hibernate-jpa-2.1-api (1.0.0.Final) and hibernate-entitymanager (4.3.6.Final).
Is there any JPA 2.1 compliant way to get around this?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the latest status of this issue at Hibernate JIRA. Feel free to accept the answer @Manuel Z

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: this bug has been resolved in the latest Hibernate [5.0.0.Beta1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.Beta1) as part of JIRA issue [HHH-8697](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8697) and will be in Hibernate 4.3.9 as soon as it is released from the [4.3.9-SNAPSHOT](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.9-SNAPSHOT/) version

If you don't want to upgrade to the beta version, you can use a workaround: take a look at [JPA/Hibernate map null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778346/jpa-hibernate-map-null) which explains using the getter and setter to implement your logic.